# rake db:migrate fails with error:"rake aborted! undefined method `deprecate' for #<Rake::Application:0x1e0c6c0>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Spent some time without programming on rails and now that I "came back" things have gone wrong.
I installed ruby 1.9.2-p0 and sticked to rails 3.0.1.Updated all gems and bundle runs successfully.Created a new rails app and created a migration but when run

```
rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `deprecate' for #<Rake::Application:0x1e0c6c0>
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks/documentation.rake:1:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:15:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `each'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/tasks.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `require'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:213:in `initialize_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:139:in `load_tasks'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
D:/sites/hebrew_learning/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
C:/Ruby192/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
```

I'm indeed lost here, so any tip will be highly appreciated

EDIT:

After running

```
bundle exec rake
```

I get:

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
WARNING: Global access to Rake DSL methods is deprecated.  Please include
...  Rake::DSL into classes and modules which use the Rake DSL methods.
WARNING: DSL method HebrewLearning::Application#task called at C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:214:in `initialize_tasks'
You have 1 pending migrations:
20111104081644 CreateUsers
Run "rake db:migrate" to update your database then try again.
```

Comment: Can you put the code of your migration?

Comment: Do you mean the XXXXXXXXXX_migration_name.rb file?

Comment: @jdeseno I run bundle exec rake db:migrate and it worked.Afterwards I uninstall my rake 0.9.2.2 then reinstalled and it works now with the common "rake db:migrate"... but I have no idea why!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rails 3.0.1, you can try this in your gemfile :

```
gem 'rake' , '0.8.7'
```

or try to migrate to 3.0.9 changing in your gemfile.

After that run :

```
bundle update
```

Bye

Comment: I second that .. I ran into this with the earlier rails 3 versions .Switching rake to version '0.8.7' should fix the problem.